# Solving allocation through cost minimization

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have limited knowledge when it comes to math notation so please excuse my crude example:

I am looking to allocate a number of units into boxes in a way that minimizes a total cost. Boxes have a known **(1)** maximum they can hold, **(2)** a minimum they can hold (always non-negative but sometimes a value), and each box has a **(3)** cost per unit.

**Example:** I have a pile of units totaling **100** units that must be separated into **n** boxes ($x_1, x_2, x_3, ... x_n$).

Where number of boxes **n** = 3,

***Constraints:***

Known **maximum** number of units a box can hold ($x_1 \leq 45$, $x_2 \leq 45$, $x_3 \leq 50$).

Known **minimum** number of units a box can hold ($x_1 \geq 15$, $x_2 \leq 0$, $x_3 \leq 0$).

Known **cost** (**C**) associated with putting units into a box is ($c_{x_1}=1$, $c_{x_1}=2, c_{x_1}=3$).

***Minimize:*** $y = \sum_{i=1}^n{(X_i*C_i)}$

or $y = x_1*c_{x_1} + x_2*c_{x_2} + x_3*c_{x_3}$

subject to the above constraints, to solve the units per box.

This example is simple enough to solve without any calculus but for more intimidating problems I am guessing one can use Lagrange optimization but I can't quite get over the hump of inequality constraints/using slack variables. How can I solve this?

Any help and/or easy to digest references for tackling this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is often called a *knapsack* problem which you can search for if you want sources and algorithms, but I am no expert at discrete optimization.

Comment: Thank you for that key reference, I'm googling now!